# On weak convergence of Borel measures on space with clopen base

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact complete separable metric space. Suppose that $X$ has a clopen base $\mathcal A$. Let $\mu_n$ be a sequence of Borel probability measures, prove that $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ if $\mu_n(A)\rightarrow \mu(A)$ for all $A\in \mathcal A$.

I found similar answers assuming that $\mathcal A$ is closed under intersections ($A_1\in \mathcal A$ and $A_2\in \mathcal A$ implies $A_1\cap A_2\in \mathcal A$), but doesn't work in my situation.

Comment: It seems redundant to say that $X$ is separable and complete since a compact metric space is automatically complete and separable.

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks, you are right.